# iPad display gamma differences between models

Tags: ipad, colors, retina-display, gamma

I have a project and the background color for UIView is ok in iPad Mini 1. The color is FEEB04.

But testing in iPad 2 Air the gamma is too bright.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Well, Apple has a [history](http://www.poynton.com/notes/colour_and_gamma/GammaFAQ.html#Macintosh) of using gamma to suit it's target audience's perceived needs. This couldbe a continuation of that - altering gamma as a substitute to more involved methods to counter the simultaneous contrast effect (also explained in the gamma faq) occurring when staring at your pad in lighter or darker conditions than anticipated.

That's somthing that could be "wrong".